# Color Conversion RGB to HSV using formula

Tags: java

I am asked to write a program based on java to convert colors from RGB to HSV , but I am not allowed to use java.awt.Color, so far my efforts got me to this level, I don't know how to make console to read the other methods it just reads the main method..

```
public class colorconversion {


public static void main(String[] args) {

 System.out.println("nope");
}

void RGBtoHSV( float r, float g, float b, float h, float s, float v )
{
r=Input.readFloat();
float min, max, delta;
min = MIN( r, g, b );
max = MAX( r, g, b );
v = max;                // v
delta = max - min;
if( max != 0 )
    s = delta / max;        // s
else {
    // r = g = b = 0        // s = 0, v is undefined
    s = 0;
    h = -1;
    return;
}
if( r == max )
    h = ( g - b ) / delta;      // between yellow & magenta
else if( g == max )
    h = 2 + ( b - r ) / delta;  // between cyan & yellow
else
    h = 4 + ( r - g ) / delta;  // between magenta & cyan
h = 60;             // degrees
if( h < 0 )
    h += 360;
}
void HSVtoRGB( float r, float g, float b, float h, float s, float v )
{
int i;
float f, p, q, t;
if( s == 0 ) {
    // achromatic (grey)
    r = g = b = v;
    return;
}
h /= 60;            // sector 0 to 5
i = floor( h );
f = h - i;          // factorial part of h
p = v * ( 1 - s );
q = v * ( 1 - s * f );
t = v * ( 1 - s * ( 1 - f ) );
switch( i ) {
    case 0:
        r = v;
        g = t;
        b = p;
        break;
    case 1:
        r = q;
        g = v;
        b = p;
        break;
    case 2:
        r = p;
        g = v;
        b = t;
        break;
    case 3:
        r = p;
        g = q;
        b = v;
        break;
    case 4:
        r = t;
        g = p;
        b = v;
        break;
    default:        // case 5:
        r = v;
        g = p;
        b = q;
        break;
  }
  }


    private static float MAX(float r, float g, float b) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   return 0;
  }

   private static float MIN(float r, float g, float b) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 return 0;
  }

  private static int floor(float h) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 return 0;
  } }
```

Comment: Please explain what is wrong with it.

Comment: shows syntax error for void HSVtoRGB

Comment: Extra brace before declaration of MAX.

Comment: `r = g = b = v;` ... and what should this do? You're returning after this assignment, therefore no one can use it. To make it short, the whole `HSVtoRGB` method cannot achieve his task.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I removed it but the error stands....

Comment: By not giving the error message, you don't help us.

Comment: I cannot remove , it is for the main method up there .. and when I put it up there the program doesn't run, since main method becomes empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are declaring methods inside `main`:

```
class ClassName {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        void methodInsideMain() {
        }
    }
}
```

Methods cannot be inside other methods in Java. Move those methods out:

```
class ClassName {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    }
    static void methodOutsideMain() {
    }
}
```

In your code, as you have shown it, `RGBtoHSV` and `HSVtoRGB` are the methods declared inside `main`. There are no other compilation errors.

Comment: I already tried it but since inside Main method is empety doesn't run anything .... even if I change the second method (written in ur example ) to the public one still doesn't run and says "public static void main(String[] args)"

Comment: Well after you've fixed the compilation errors, you still have to write the rest of the program. I believe I've shown you how to fix your compilation error.

Comment: I thought I wrote it :D could you please tell me how to make this happen ? It has driven me crazy since 5 hours ago...

Comment: Check your braces and indentation, make sure every method is outside another method and inside the class. If you have done this and it still does not compile, then you have not done it correctly or the code you have shown us is different because this is the only compilation error shown. Once it compiles, you need to write the rest of the program before it will *do* something.

Comment: If there is still a problem, please read what is [on-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) to decide whether you should edit your question to tell us exactly what that problem is or ask a different question.

Comment: I already edited the question... those errors were just a fake layer on real problem which you already mentioned above now I have new question so I edited the question...